# Spock: Return input parameter in Stubs

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, spock

Given an method with a parameter *in Java*, e.g.

```
public class Foo {
   public Bar theBar(Bar bar) { /*... */ }   
}
```

When stubbing/ mocking foo, how do I tell it to accept any argument and return it? (*Groovy*)

```
def fooStub = Stub(Foo) {
  theBar(/*what to pass here*/) >> { x -> x }
}
```

As you can see I passed the identity function. However I do not know what to pass as argument. `_` does not work because it is an `ArrayList` and thus not of type `Bar`

Comment: Do you have `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked` on your spec? could you post your whole code, there is no reason why `_` shouldn't work.

Comment: Just ran into the same setup and situation. Trying to stub a Java class from Spock + Groovy and I only want to return the method's input, no more no less. Since I have no idea what's going on I simply leave my solution as a comment and I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me. It seems the `x` input before the arrow is actually the entire arguments list of the method call? Doing the following solves the problem: `theBar(_) >> { args -> args.get(0) }`. But why is that necessary? How to express this correctly without any hacks?

Answer (score 10):

You can stub `Foo` class in following way:

```
Foo foo = Stub(Foo)
foo.theBar(_ as Bar) >> { Bar bar -> bar }
```

And here is full example:

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable
import spock.lang.Specification

class StubbingSpec extends Specification {

    def "stub that returns passed parameter"() {
        given:
        Foo foo = Stub(Foo)
        foo.theBar(_ as Bar) >> { Bar bar -> bar }

        when:
        def result = foo.theBar(new Bar(10))

        then:
        result.id == 10
    }

    static class Foo {
        Bar theBar(Bar bar) {
            return null
        }
    }

    @Immutable
    static class Bar {
        Integer id
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the same with `Foo` and `Bar` being Java classes?

Comment: @user3001 Yes, it works exactly the same when `Foo` and `Bar` are Java classes, just tested this example and got same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. `_` is the right thing to pass. Why do you think it is an `ArrayList`? It is of type `Object` and can be used for anything.

Comment: That means that in Java, it has the wrong type (not `Bar`), right?

Comment: So? Spock is Groovy based, you cannot use Spock with Java.